# Proyecto en Laravel ya no funciona al cambiar de carpeta, error: Carbon\Carbon::setLastErrors():

Tags: laravel, xampp

Tuve que desinstalar xampp y volver a instalar, antes de eso, comprimí el proyecto y lo moví de carpeta, al regresarlo a la carpeta  `C:\xampp\htdocs` el proyecto ya no corrió. Nunca había tenido que moverlo, no se como solucionar el error, al investigar dice que actualice `composer` pero aun sigue dando error.

Este es el error que me da al correr con `php artisan serve`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Errores del composer install
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si hay archivos php en la carpeta bootstrap/cache y borralos. Luego haz `php artisan config: cache `. El error no está fácil de debugear dado que ocurre en un método privado de Carbón y la traza del error no permite ver desde donde se invoca el método previo (rawCreateFromFormat) que se usa de muchas partes de la aplicación. Podrías además ver si tú nuevo xampp cambió la versión de php?

Comment: borre los archivos y puse `php artisan config: cache ` pero aun muestra el error

Comment: Prueba eliminar (o renombrar si quieres tener un backup) el directorio `vendor` y el archivo `composer.lock` y luego correr `composer install`. Tambien en el directorio `storage/framework` suele haber cache que podrias eliminar

Comment: seguí los pasos, sigue sin funcionar, `composer install` me da 3 errores

Comment: Que errores te dá composer install?

Comment: ya no son 3, son 43 no entiendo el porque, antes no me habìa salido nada. Edite la pregunta para mostrar los errores que salen.

Comment: Ah, probablemente es por lo que te dijeron antes, en *tú nuevo xampp cambió la versión de php*.  Borreste el `composer.lock`, cierto? Para resolverlo tendrías que decidir para qué versión de php quieres hacer tu proyecto, y luego adaptar el proyecto o el xampp a eso